# distinct with highest value using django orm

Tags: mysql, django

I have records in a table like that

```
ID  Name            priority
1   MyString        12
2   Search          20
3   MyString        50
4   MyString        10
5   Search          7
```

I want to get distinct rows with highest priority value. For example, the above example should give the following result

```
ID  Name            priority
2   Search          20
3   MyString        50
```

I was going through the docs and found out that distinct on columns cannot be found out on mysql. So I tried to perform a group-by and sort (descending on priority column).

I tried this

```
model_name.objects.all().values('name','priority','id').annotate(Count('search_name')).order_by('-priority')
```

But I am not getting the desired result. Is it possible to do this in a single orm query.

I am using django 1.6 and mysql as my database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the .distinct() method to your query? Django ORM has the distinct() method. I hope this helps you:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: As mentioned in the docs -- distinct on columns will not work on mysql. Its only implemented for PostgreSQL till now